# XML::Twig changes erased

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

The program below gives me weird output that I cannot explain:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = 
q{<block>
    <foo>bar baz</foo>
</block>};

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        TwigHandlers => {foo => \&foo, block => \&block},
    );

print "after parse: " . $twig->parse($xml)->sprint;


sub foo {
    my ( $twig, $foo ) = @_;

    my $text = $foo->sprint("don't print outside element");
    my $newSummary = XML::Twig::Elt->parse( '<p><i>' . $text . '</i></p>' );
    $newSummary->paste( 'before', $foo);
    my $parent = $foo->parent;
    # $foo->delete;
    print "foo: " . $parent->sprint . "\n\n";
}

sub block {
    my ($twig, $block) = @_;
    print "block: " . $block->sprint . "\n\n";
}
```

It prints the following:

```
foo: <block><p><i>bar baz</i></p><foo>bar baz</foo></block>

block: <block><p><i>bar baz</i></p><foo>bar baz</foo></block>

after parse: <block><foo>bar baz</foo></block>
```

So I am modifying the twig inside of the `foo` handler, the change is sticking around for the `block` handler to see it, but then when processing is all done, the change goes away. What is going on here? How can I make my change stick for the lifetime of the twig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug, or at least a problem with scoping: the new element seems to be garbage collected when the parse finishes.

One way to avoid this is to add a `copy` to the creation of the element:

```
my $newSummary = XML::Twig::Elt->parse( '<p><i>' . $text . '</i></p>' )->copy;
```

Comment: indeed it was a bug in the object destruction, it is fixed in the development version here: http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/ or on github: https://github.com/mirod/xmltwig

Comment: Thanks for that! If I had been sure it were a bug, I would have submitted it to you. When do you think you will release 3.42 to CPAN?

Comment: It's a bit late for me tonight, so how about tomorrow morning?